# How to make CMake actually link with the library it finds with find_library

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 with glew 1.10 installed by default. I want to use the newest glew 1.13, but sudo apt-get remove libglew1.10 is not an option, because ubuntu-desktop depends on it, I accidentally do it once and I had to go to recovery mode to reinstall everything back.

I downloaded the latest glew 1.13 and sudo make install. The glew 1.13 library got installed under /usr/lib64/libGLEW.so. The old 1.10 one is still at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so. The header files at /usr/include/GL/glew.h and /usr/include/GL/wglew.h do got replaced with the ones from 1.13.

In my FindGLEW.cmake, it does successfully find the correct libGLEW.so after I run cmake ..

```
find_library(GLEW_LIBRARY NO_DEFAULT_PATH
    NAMES
        GLEW glew
    PATHS
        /usr/lib64
        DOC "The GLEW library"
        )
```

It could be verified by ccmake .. , the GLEW_LIBRARY section does show /usr/lib64/libGLEW.so.

However when I compile the code, I am still getting undefined reference errors from methods only available from glew 1.13, further checking with ldd mylib.so, it shows

```
libGLEW.so.1.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.10 (0x00007f10d130b000)
```

Meaning somehow it is still linking against the old shared library from 1.10 and putting the directory search priority at etc/ld.so.conf.d/* higher than the path specified by find_library by default. How can I solve this?

As a side note, the exact same code with the exact same CMakeLists compiles without a problem on a server without libglew1.10 and ubuntu-desktop installed.

Comment: Using the `find_library` macro, you only "find" the library. You don't link with this. You have to add the GLEW_LIBRARY value to `add_library`. Did you check this?
You may also have a look to : link_directories() to make sure you link with the glew from /usr/lib64 ?

Comment: @P.Brunet I did `target_link_libraries(myproject ${GLEW_LIBRARY})` . Not sure about link_directories but even the official CMake documents discouraged against using it

Comment: @user3667089, it might be easiest to install a newer version of ubuntu that has a newer glew. might not be what you want to hear, but i thoguht I would mention it..

Answer (score 0):

ldd as well as ld take runtime shared library loader information into account (via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env var).

So make sure to do the following before linking your program:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

More information: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Comment: thanks for the answer but /usr/lib64 is already added in the path by find_library, so adding it again to LD_LIBRARY_PATH is redundant, it's just that there are two libGLEW.so (exact same name) in the path, and somehow ubuntu decide to pick the one from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ over /usr/lib64

Comment: Relink `mylib.so` with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set?

Comment: added /usr/lib64 into LD_LIBRARY_PATH but still links the wrong one, LD_LIBRARY_PATH still has lower priority than default search path. Have you try it and does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

find_library, finds the exact path of the library file (*so* or *dll* depending on platform). After that you still need to do add_library to link to it. The following worked for me when I had this issue with another library:

```
find_library(GLEW_LIBRARY NO_DEFAULT_PATH
    NAMES GLEW glew 
    PATHS /usr/lib64
    DOC "The GLEW library")

add_library(glew SHARED IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(glew 
    PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${GLEW_LIBRARY})

target_link_libraries(myproject glew)
```